# app-engine endpoint method taking user object

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, user-object

I have an endpoint method that requires a user object. Would I do the following? It seems a bit strange since I could get user using `endpoints.get_current_user()`

```
@endpoints.method(FriendListRequest, FriendListResponse,
                  path='scores', http_method='POST',
                  name='scores.list')
def friend_list(self, request):
  # work would go here
```

Then the FriendListRequest would be

```
class FriendListRequest(messages.Message):
    user_object = messages.Field(1, required=True)
```

The reason I need the `User` object is because I must use the User email to query and find the friends of said user.

Comment: You need to pass a secure token (like in oauth2) and not the user object, otherwise anyone can claim he can be anyone.

Comment: Using `messages.Field` to hold your user object will fail.

Answer (score 3):

To securely authenticate a user, Cloud Endpoints provides simple OAuth 2.0 support. Instead of passing a user object (insecure) in with the request, the request message can be a `VoidMessage` and you can rely on the Authorization header, which contains the OAuth 2.0 token for the user.

To actually get the current user, you will call `endpoints.get_current_user()`; this will require adding `allowed_client_ids` and/or `audiences` in either the `@endpoints.method` decorator or the the `@endpoints.api` method. See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#allowed-clients-and-audiences) for more info.

For example, on the API:

```
@endpoints.api(name='myapi', ...,
               allowed_client_ids=[MY_CLIENT_ID])
class MyApi(...):

    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, FriendListResponse,
                      path='scores', http_method='POST',
                      name='scores.list')
    def friend_list(self, request):
        user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        # work would go here
```

or, on the method:

```
    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, FriendListResponse,
                      path='scores', http_method='POST',
                      name='scores.list',
                      allowed_client_ids=[MY_CLIENT_ID])
    def friend_list(self, request):
        user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        # work would go here
```

Comment: This will require adding `allowed_client_ids` and or `audiences` in either the `@endpoints.method` decorator or the the `@endpoints.api` method. See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#allowed-clients-and-audiences) for more info.

Comment: Do you mind if I update your answer to include this information?

Answer (score 0):

Create a user object using users and pass the same

A User instance can be also constructed from an email address:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

user = users.User("A***.j***@gmail.com")
```